# Is it possible to export/import content types from one site to another

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

is there a way to import/export content types between diff Drupal websites?, assuming they are the same versions of Drupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options:

- [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features)

  The features module enables the capture and management of features in Drupal. A feature is a collection of Drupal entities which taken together satisfy a certain use-case.
- [Bundle Copy](https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_copy)